# Incomplete type in DLL function parameters cause incorrect result

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, incomplete-type

Recently I'm being bitten by the incorrect result related to self-invented DLL function.
In the following code snippets, if I change the condition of `#if..#else..` in `MyTest.cpp`, the results differ. Can someone explain it? thanks.

DLLType.h

```
#pragma once
struct timeval { long tv_sec, tv_usec; };
```

DLLHead.h

```
#pragma once
#ifdef _MY_EXPORT
__declspec(dllexport) struct timeval ToSocketTime(long);
#else
__declspec(dllimport) struct timeval ToSocketTime(long);
#endif
```

DLLImpl.cpp

```
// cl /MD /D_MY_EXPORT DLLImpl.cpp /link /DLL
#include "DLLType.h"
#include <numeric> // std::ldiv
#include <cstdio> // printf

__declspec(dllexport) struct timeval ToSocketTime(long ms) {
    const std::ldiv_t div = std::ldiv(ms, 1000);
    printf("ldiv(%ld, 1000) => %ld, %ld\n", ms, div.quot, div.rem);

    struct timeval ret = { div.quot, div.rem * 1000 };
    printf("timeval inside dll: %ld, %ld\n", ret.tv_sec, ret.tv_usec);
    return ret;
}
```

MyTest.cpp

```
// cl /MD DLLImpl.lib MyTest.cpp

#if 0 // ok
#include "DLLType.h"
#include "DLLHead.h"
#else // error
#include "DLLHead.h"
#include "DLLType.h"
#endif

#include <cstdio> // printf
int main() {
    long ms = 5000L; // time in milliseconds
    struct timeval ret = ToSocketTime(ms);
    printf("ToSocketTime(%ld) => %ld, %ld\n", ms, ret.tv_sec, ret.tv_usec);
}
```

If `#if..` part is choosen, `ToSocketTime` produce correct result:

```
$ cl /MD /D_MY_EXPORT DLLImpl.cpp /link /DLL && cl /MD DLLImpl.lib MyTest.cpp && MyTest.exe
用于 80x86 的 Microsoft (R) 32 位 C/C++ 优化编译器 16.00.40219.01 版
... skipped ...
/out:MyTest.exe
DLLImpl.lib
MyTest.obj
ldiv(5000, 1000) => 5, 0
timeval inside dll: 5, 0
ToSocketTime(5000) => 5, 0
```

But if it is changed to `#else...`, the result is quite strange, as follows:

```
$ cl /MD /D_MY_EXPORT DLLImpl.cpp /link /DLL && cl /MD DLLImpl.lib MyTest.cpp && MyTest.exe
用于 80x86 的 Microsoft (R) 32 位 C/C++ 优化编译器 16.00.40219.01 版
... skipped ...
/out:MyTest.exe
DLLImpl.lib
MyTest.obj
ldiv(16449096, 1000) => 16449, 96
timeval inside dll: 16449, 96000
ToSocketTime(5000) => 0, 13905972
```

1. If I replace `DLLType.h` by `winsock2.h`, problem still occur.
2. If I change compiler from `Visual Studio 2010` x86 to `Visual Studio 2019` x86, both `#if..` and `#else..` produce correct results.

Comment: Using a type name that doesn't conflict with system types might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/ns-winsock-timeval

Comment: Sadly, change type name doesn't help, I have tried.

Comment: @jgx please update your question to show what you tried that is not working.

Comment: When you say you changed from VS 2010 to 2019, were you using 2010 for everything or were you mixing versions? Finding a bug in a 11 year old compiler isn't too surprising

Comment: @Alan Birtles I'm use VS2010 for everything. For historical reasons, my company still use VS2010 for many projects, and both for DLLs and their client code, almost because of Windows XP.

Comment: Here's my guess. There are generally two ways to return a value from a function: if the return type is small enough, it can be returned on a CPU register; otherwise the caller passes an additional hidden parameter to the function - a pointer to a block of memory into which the function should write its return value. (continued)

Comment: Now, you declare a function whose return type is incomplete, its size unknown, so the compiler doesn't know which of these two ways to use. It appears to err on the more general side and pass an extra pointer. But of course the actual function knowns the size is in fact small enough. As a result, a) the function doesn't expect the extra parameter and mistakes the pointer to return value for its `ms` parameter. b) The function puts return value on the register, but the caller looks at the buffer whose pointer it passed - which is uninitialized, containing random garbage.

Comment: The right way to fix it is to have `DLLHead.h` include `DLLType.h`, so the header defines the types it uses.